# Swimming against the tide in the past century: remarkable achievements that arose in contrast to the general view of mathematicians

Tags: soft-question, ho.history-overview, big-list, mathematical-philosophy

I would like to ask a question inspired by the title of a book by Sir [Roger Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Penrose) ([1]). The germ of this is to ask about the role, if any, of the fashion in research of pure and applied mathematics.

I'm going to focus the post (and modulate my genuine idea) about an aspect that I think can be discussed here from an historical and mathematical point of view, according to the following:

> **Question.** I would like to know what are examples of remarkable achievements (in your research subject or another that you know) that arose against the general view/work of the mathematical community since the year 1900 up to the year 1975. *Refer* the literature if you need it. **Many thanks.**

**An example** is the mention that the author of [2] (as I interpret it) about [Lennart Carleson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennart_Carleson) and a conjecture due to [Lusin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin%27s_theorem) in the second paragraph of page 671 (the article is in Spanish).

Your answer can refer to (for the research of pure or applied mathematics, and mathematical physics) unexpected proofs of old unsolved problems, surprising examples or counterexamples, approaches or mathematical methods that defied the contemporary (ordinary, mainstream) approaches, incredible modulizations solving difficult problems,... all these in the context of the question that is: **the proponents/teams of these solutions and ideas swam against the work of the contemporary mathematics that they knew at the time.**

*You can refer to the literature for the statements of the theorems, examples, methods,... if you need it. Also from my side it is welcome if you want to add some of your own historical remarks about the  mathematical context concerning the answer that you provide us: that's historical remarks (if there is some philosophical issue also) emphasizing why the novelty work of the mathematician that you evoke was swimming against the tide of the contemporary ideas of those years.

### References:

[1] Roger Penrose, *Fashion, Faith, and Fantasy in the New Physics of the Universe*,  Princeton University Press (2016).

[2] Javier Duoandikoetxea, *200 años de convergencia de las series de Fourier*, La Gaceta de la Real Sociedad Matematica Española, Vol. 10, Nº 3, (2007), pages 651-677.

Comment: I hope that the question is interesting for your site, please add your feedback.

Comment: Many thanks for your edit @Wojowu

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question (especially because the "example" is not explained in the post); but: Paul Cohen's work on the continuum hypothesis probably qualifies. In his own words, at the time he developed the technique of forcing, he "had the feeling that people thought the problem [i.e., the Continuum Hypothesis] was hopeless, since there was no new way of constructing models of set theory. Indeed, they thought you had to be slightly crazy even to think about the problem."

Comment: Swimming against the tide is more or less the definition of world-class mathematics, either by pushing some known tools beyond what was thought possible or by inventing/discovering unexpected tools.

Comment: History questions may belong at https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RolandBacher, some world-class math goes with the tide! E.g. Wiles's proof of FLT in 1993-95 followed a path suggested by Taniyama-Shimura-Weil and used work on "the main conjecture of Iwasawa theory" from 1984, plus work for which Ken Ribet had received the Fermat prize in 1989. So rather than going against the trend, Wiles represented its triumph.

Comment: We can take this question in two different directions: "proved something remarkable following an approach that was thought to be hopeless" and "proved something that was widely believed to be false".

Comment: Somewhat related: [Mathematicians whose works were criticized by contemporaries but became widely accepted later](https://mathoverflow.net/q/121565) and [Modern results that are widely known, yet which at the time were ignored, not accepted or criticized](https://mathoverflow.net/q/415458) and [What are some famous rejections of correct mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/13896)

Comment: @HAHelfgott Regarding "proving something that was widely believed to be false," see [Examples of conjectures that were widely believed to be true but later proved false](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95865).

Comment: @Matt F. Nobody is perfect! (Final words from 'Some like it hot').

Comment: Many thanks for all users, and professors in answers, when I can I read the answers and I accept an answer This is an excellent reference for your colleagues (professors here in the site MathOverflow). Many thanks again.

Comment: I don't have time to post a complete answer, or to look up the names involved -- but I remember hearing that when it was proved that every recursively enumerable set is diophantine, it was a shock as most mathematicians believed there was no way the set of prime numbers could possibly be diophantine, and there were some efforts to try to prove that it was not (and few to try to show it was).

Comment: A story I heard is that Stephen Smale proved that sphere eversion is possible for even dimensional spheres using vary general arguments, but there was so much doubt about his result that he went ahead and constructed a specific sphere eversion for the $2$-sphere.

Comment: Godel’s Incompleteness theorems seem like the canonical answer to this.  I know of no more unexpected result in the history of mathematics.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Good example. See page 564 of this [interview with Martin Davis](https://www.ams.org/notices/200805/tx080500560p.pdf).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems better for [HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @LSpice, for most questions on math after ~1850, I think MO makes more sense; for before that, I think HSM is good.

Comment: @MattF., [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420158/swimming-against-the-tide-in-the-past-century-remarkable-achievements-that-aros#comment1079410_420158), of course everyone has their own guidelines, and that's why it (appropriately) requires multiple votes to close.  To me, the dividing line isn't time, but whether one is discussing math that *has* happened (history) or math that *is* happening (research, and hence likely appropriate for MO); but norms come out of community, not any one person's ideas, so the most important thing is what the community thinks!

Comment: @HAHelfgott another option is someone who proved things in a field which was completely unfashionable (they were thought to be "wasting their time"), but then later became fashionable.

Comment: Many thanks for all answers and comments, in special the comment about the excellent mathematician Harald Helfgott. I've accept an answer, but all contributions are excellent.

Comment: I accept an answer, many thanks for your feedback @LSpice I hope that you've the best week.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that before Kolmogorov it was believed that probability theory could never be made rigorous. This was certainly a major achievement of early 20th century mathematics, but I'm really not sure to which degree he was "swimming against the tide". Maybe someone who knows more about the history of probability theory can say something about this?

Comment: Also, speaking of "swimming against the tide", L. E. J. Brouwer's school of intuitionism comes to mind, but I'm really not sure which (if any) "remarkable achievements" came out of that.

Comment: Just noting here the "swimming against the tide" is also name of a memoir about VI Arnold, so his work could probably be apt here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Siegel zeros and other "illusory worlds": building theories around hypotheses believed to be false](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397585/siegel-zeros-and-other-illusory-worlds-building-theories-around-hypotheses-be)

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @BlueRaja

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After mathematicians had been been taught for decades that a consistent theory of the calculus based on infinitesimals was impossible, Abraham Robinson was certainly swimming against the tide when he proved otherwise.

Robinson, A. (1961): *Non-standard analysis*, Indagationes Mathematicae 23, pp. 432-440.

Robinson, A. (1966): *Non-standard Analysis*, North-Holland Publishing Company, Amsterdam.

Comment: And Jerome Keisler's calculus text (and "instructor's manual" for it).

Answer (score 34):

This is a well-known example, but it is [Georg Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor). While ultimately many of his ideas have become part of the bedrock of mathematics, taught to every undergraduate maths student, he faced opposition in his day.

[Joseph Dauben's biography](https://books.google.com/books/about/Georg_Cantor.html?id=n3t4b6GUlhAC) gives a thorough explanation of the opposition his ideas faced and how he responded. For example, Cantor's original proof of the uncountability of the reals appears as a lemma in the innocuously titled "On a property of the collection of all real algebraic numbers", downplaying the true novelty of the result to sneak it into a journal edited by [Kronecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leopold_Kronecker).

Comment: This is an excellent example but did any of the relevant work happen between 1900 and 1975?

Comment: @WillSawin, no, the criticism he received and the loss of his son led to poor mental health and no substantial math after 1900; see Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Cantor)

Comment: "Cantor suffered his first known bout of depression in May 1884. Criticism weighed on his mind: every one of the fifty-two letters he wrote to Mittag-Leffler in 1884 mentioned Kronecker, [e.g.] 'I don't know when I shall return to my scientific work. I limit myself to the most necessary duty of my lectures; how much happier I would be to be scientifically active, if only I had the necessary mental freshness.' Soon after [his 1899] hospitalization, Cantor's youngest son Rudolph died suddenly...and this tragedy drained Cantor of much of his passion for mathematics."

Comment: Cantor is a definite 1st by large in this list, with his set theory. It was such a straightforward violation of the ancient taboos in mathematics/philosophy. It induced reactions in the non-cantorial mathematics such as intuitionism and category theory, quite remarkable in themselves. Nothing comparable can be observed even wrt NSA that would be my 2nd (very distant from the 1st) example.

Comment: In smashing the Continuum in to dust, Cantor was a vandal.

Comment: Weierstrass (in a letter to Mittag-Leffler IIRC) wrote that he had previously believed there to be one kind of infinity.  Cantor's work convinced him otherwise.  At least some did side with Cantor, even in his lifetime.

Comment: @PaulTaylor To my way of thinking, the topology (a set of overlapping open intervals*) is the glue that keeps them together. (*well, also disconnected open sets, but the intervals are a basis)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger It's like difference between wood and chipboard: you only need to glue it back together because you had ground it into dust.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei, how was category theory a reaction to Cantor? Of course Cantor came before category theory, but so much else happened in math between 1887 and 1945 that I don't see a strong connection.

Comment: @Matt F, they just kept trying hard to destroy Cantor. Category theory came up as one of very few attempts that succeeded if not to really destroy set theory but at least to gain some kind of own ground.

Answer (score 27):

In the first decades of the 20th century, $p$-adic analysis (or valuation theory more generally) was regarded by many as rather exotic. After Hensel's work there was a steady development by Strassmann, Kürschák, Krasner, et al., and $p$-adic numbers were the direct inspiration for Steinitz's major paper that turned field theory into a new part of abstract algebra, but for a long time it was not considered fully mainstream mathematics. Bourbaki has some discussion about this in the Historical Notes to their text on commutative algebra.

If I should list an example of a major result that was proved by these methods that had not been proved before by other methods, I'd pick Dwork's proof of the rationality of the zeta-function of an arbitrary algebraic variety over a finite field. He did this without smoothness assumptions, which went beyond Weil's original conjectures at least as far as rationality is concerned.

Another example in number theory might be the Artin reciprocity law, although only for a few years.  Artin said that when he discussed it with other people while he was trying to prove it, they laughed at him and said it couldn't possibly be true. But after he proved his reciprocity law, it was recognized as the central result in class field theory.

Answer (score 23):

Herbert Busemann's work on differential geometry is a good example. See his many [characterizations of Euclidean space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47882/characterizations-of-euclidean-space) -- without any requirement of differentiability! They are all from his 1955 masterpiece, *The Geometry of Geodesics*.

The general trend of geometry was and mostly is focused on differentiable manifolds, following Hassler Whitney's 1936 definition, and often specializing to Riemannian geometry. The small group of people interested in non-Riemannian metric geometry, like Hanno Rund in 1959, mostly wrote about *The Differential Geometry of Finsler Spaces*. (If you doubt the smallness of the non-Riemannian trend, consider: Can you define a Riemannian manifold? And have you ever learned the definition of a Finsler manifold?)

Against the differentiable trend and the Riemannian trend that are often too pervasive to notice, Busemann took an axiomatic and metric approach, in the spirit of David Hilbert's 1899 *Foundations of Geometry*. He got the above characterizations of Euclidean spaces; he wrote about [areas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164053/areas-of-triangles-in-non-riemannian-metric-spaces) in those spaces; along the way he defined the [Busemann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busemann_function) for which his name most often comes up today.

But Busemann's work is little known, despite his clear 1955 presentation, and convenient 1970 collection of *Recent Synthetic Differential Geometry*. This is why I've written so much about Busemann here, without being in a math department. When someone [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379416/is-it-possible-to-do-calculus-and-differential-geometry-the-old-school-way-with) about an old-school approach like this, I answered but the question was still closed as unclear! And I've often commented to clear up [confusions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34394/g-spaces-and-manifolds), or distinguish [Lawvere's thing](https://mathoverflow.net/a/362006/44143) with the same name, or respond to a recent graduate's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417453/defining-a-probability-distribution-on-each-tangent-space-of-a-manifold#comment1072056_417463) that "differential geometry is all about manifolds?"

If you want to learn about Busemann's approach, you can start with the *Geometry of Geodesics*, or the links here. As I've said elsewhere: If you think "[the weaker notion is the appropriate notion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333204/introduction-to-finsler-manifolds-from-the-metric-geometry-point-of-view-possib)", you're likely to enjoy Busemann a lot. And, by comparison with coordinatized Finsler geometry, approaches like Busemann's make it easier to [generalize geometry well](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271155/44143).

Comment: [Tissot ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix) are to a Riemannian metric as Tissot non-ellipses are to Finsler metrics, right?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger, that’s a good image but the question is: which possible non-ellipses and non-ellipsoids are associated with Finsler metrics?

Comment: You may have meant to link directly to your [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/346560) giving Busemann's characterisations, perhaps not just to the [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47882/characterizations-of-euclidean-space) about characterisations (in any spirit).

Comment: @LSpice, I like linking to that question to emphasize the naturalness of the question that Busemann was answering.

Answer (score 15):

I think a good example would be the first rigorous construction of an interacting quantum field theory by Edward Nelson using methods from probability theory.

Quoting from the article https://www.princeton.edu/news/2014/09/19/edward-nelson-nonconformist-who-sparked-quantum-field-theory-revolution-dies-82?section=topstories

> That probabilistic approach had been attempted before, and many mathematicians had written it off as impossible, said Eric Carlen, a professor of mathematics at Rutgers University who studied under Nelson before receiving his Ph.D. from Princeton in 1984. Nelson’s colleague Arthur Wightman, a renowned mathematical physicist and Princeton’s Thomas D. Jones Professor Emeritus, introduced him to the problem.
>
> Nelson was told that the sort of approach he was taking had been tried and failed, but “Ed trusted his intuition over all the experts in the field and he was right,” Carlen said. “To bring forth a really new idea and bring it forth in a real polished way requires tremendous effort, concentration and focus. When he got a new idea he really followed it through to the end. And because of that, his ideas have really gone on to have a life beyond their original application.”

Comment: What was the trend in this area before Nelson? Advances usually have new ideas and are in that sense against the tide, but for a satisfying answer here I'd want to know about the prior trends.

Comment: Well I guess the prior trend would be anything except probability theory: PDE theory, spectral theory, the theory of operator algebras, and what not. Perhaps a comparison of the review articles on the matter by Glimm-Jaffe, Wightman and Nelson in Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, Vol. XXIII, 1973, would give an idea of how original Nelson's ideas were at the time.

Answer (score 14):

There are various examples of certain areas of mathematics being regarded as sterile and disconnected from the rest of mathematics, but nevertheless being pursued doggedly by some researchers, and eventually finding unexpected applications in other areas of mathematics.

Computability theory, especially the study of computably enumerable sets, is an example. Though it has been pursued ever since the mid-twentieth century, computability theory is even today regarded by most mathematicians as an arcane subject with little connection with the rest of mathematics.  However, as explained by Soare in his paper, [Computability theory and differential geometry](https://doi.org/10.2178/bsl/1102083758) (non-paywalled version [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~soare/Publications/geom.pdf)), computability theory has found unexpected applications in the work of Nabutovsky and Weinberger in differential geometry.

Another possible example is the use of model theory to attack number-theoretic problems. The [Ax–Kochen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Kochen_theorem) dates from 1965, but my impression is that for a long time, most number theorists did not think that model theory was a particularly powerful or insightful tool. That skepticism has presumably evaporated with (for example) the success of o-minimality and the spectacular proof of the [André–Oort conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9%E2%80%93Oort_conjecture).

Comment: Many thanks in special to your person for your answer.

Answer (score 11):

These examples involve an overlap among interests of mathematicians and researchers in cross-disciplinary fields--physics, chemistry, and cognitive science.

*The acceptance of group theory in theoretical physics in the early decades of the XXth century was not as straightforward as one may suppose.*

Excerpt from pg. 77 of

"[**From the Rise of the Group Concept to the Stormy Onset of Group Theory in the New Quantum Mechanics. A saga of the invariant characterization of physical objects, events and theories.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1393/ncr/i2004-10006-4)" by Bonolis

> In 1929 Slater published his influential paper “Theory of Complex Spectra” on Physical Review, showing that all results can be derived by using the simplest mathematics only [Slater 1929]. Slater discovered that by introducing the electronic spin at the very beginning of a calculation an enormous simplification could be achieved. He successfully obtained expressions for the energies of spectroscopic terms replacing considerations involving the group representation by considerations involving the three operators of angular momentum satisfying simple commutation relations.
>
> “As soon as this paper became known, it was obvious that a great many other physicists were as disgusted as I had been with the group-theoretical approach to the problem. As I heard later, there were remarks made such as ‘Slater has slain the Gruppenpest’. I believe that no other piece of work I have done was so universally popular” [Sternberg 1994, xi]. Here Slater is recalling a Goethe’s Faust parody which was staged in April 1932 at Copenhagen, on the occasion of the tenth anniversary of Bohr’s Institute. In a short scene of this memorable play, the Blegdamsvejen Faust, Slater was seen to kill a dragon representing group symmetry: “Das indizbeschuppte Vieh (der Gruppendrache), er starb an Antisymmetrie.” (The beast covered with indices scales (the group dragon) it died of antisymmetry.) Trace of this general rejection still remains in George Gamow’s original drawings [Gamow 1966].

---

Another example (albeit not quite as initially mathematically well-developed/delineated as the first) is provided in the theory of oscillating reactions in nonequilibrium thermodynamics by the history of the [Belousov-Zhabotinskii reaction](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Belousov-Zhabotinsky_reaction). See also "[An Analysis of the Belousov-Zhabotinskii Reaction](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1286&context=rhumj)" by Casey R. Gray and "[The Prehistory of the Belousov-Zhabotinsky Oscillator](https://www.dna.caltech.edu/Papers/prehistory1984.pdf)" by A. T. Winfree.

---

A third, again not as initially mathematically well-developed as the first, is in the prehistory of neural networks as presented in "[A revival of Turing's connectionist ideas: Exploring unorganized machines](https://personal.utdallas.edu/%7Eotoole/HCS6330_F12/05_teuscher00_ncpw6.pdf)" by Teuscher and Sanchez (see also [McCulloch & Pitts Publish the First Mathematical Model of a Neural Network](https://www.historyofinformation.com/detail.php?entryid=782)). In addition, neural-network models (NNMs) didn't become mainstream until well after 1970, so Turing was far ahead of his times as well as McCulloch and Pitts. One reason for the delay in acceptance of NNMs is the historical competition between the logicist's camp and the connectionist/neural-network camp in AI/cognitive science with their distinct mathematical/computational approaches as sketched in "The Improbable Machine" by Jeremey Campbell (see also "The Mind's New Science: A History of the Cognitive Revolution" by Howard Gardner).

Comment: Turing seems to have straddled both approaches to AI.

Comment: But then again, Turing believed that telepathy was real, so he also straddled many approaches to the reality of the mind :-)

Comment: Was.that before or after the forced hormone treatment? / Newton believed in the strangest things also.

Comment: Years before. It appears in his article introducing the Turing test; he says "Perhaps this psycho-kinesis might cause the machine to guess right more often than would be expected..." and that "to put the competitors into a ‘telepathy-proof room’ would satisfy all requirements [of dealing with this issue]".

Comment: I don't know the full context, but "three operators of angular momentum satisfying simple commutation relations" sure sounds like representation theory in the thinnest of disguises to me.

Comment: @LSpice, I agree. Read the article for the context. (Of course, if you are doing permutations of the rows/columns of a matrix  or addition of the reals you can couch the operations in group theoretical terms as well.)

Comment: @TomCopeland, thanks for the [recommendation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420158/swimming-against-the-tide-in-the-past-century-remarkable-achievements-that-aros/420187#comment1079444_420187).  I edited in a link to [the Bonolis article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1393/ncr/i2004-10006-4).

Comment: @LSpice, I typically don't include links that are behind paywalls, especially if they can be found at other sites via google search or at your favorite freedom-of-information site (long live that hacker ethic).

Comment: @TomCopeland, I [apologise](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1079561).  Of course, please feel free to roll back my edit (or to replace it by a [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234207946_From_the_Rise_of_the_Group_Concept_to_the_Stormy_Onset_of_Group_Theory_in_the_New_Quantum_Mechanics_A_saga_of_the_invariant_characterization_of_physical_objects_events_and_theories) or [Semantic Scholar](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/From-the-Rise-of-the-Group-Concept-to-the-Stormy-of-Bonolis-Laplace/d37b1e82468ba1d6f6f14bb1ac207bb9672121ff) link).

Comment: Ehrenfest, for example, writes in a letter to van der Waerden ''a real group plague [Gruppenpest] has broken out in our physical journals''.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda When Turing wrote his paper (1950), the work of [J. B. Rhine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Banks_Rhine) probably still seemed strong to Turing. It's clear that his acceptance of ESP was reluctant: "These disturbing phenomena seem to deny all our usual scientific ideas. How we should like to discredit them! Unfortunately the statistical evidence, at least for telepathy, is overwhelming. It is very difficult to rearrange one’s ideas so as to fit these new facts in. Once one has accepted them it does not seem a very big step to believe in ghosts and bogies."